# jquery dialog displaying ugly title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have dialog working but it looks nothing like the demo at jquery.com i have the theme css and the js files and referenced, but it looks ugly. big text and the title and 'x' are out of position. i have placed a grab at:

http://picasaweb.google.com/100992319569544717409/DialogPics

and would be grateful if someone could explain why this is happening. many thanks

```
// Help function

            function help(){ 

                $(function() {

                 $('#help').dialog(
        { 
            title:"Mail Help",
            width: 416,
            height: 340,
            modal: true,
            overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.5 }


        });$("#help").dialog('open');
          });
         }
```

this is what i have for referencing files:

```
<script src="/sample/admin/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sample/admin/js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sample/admin/js/ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="/sample/admin/js/ui.core.js"></script>

<link href="/sample/admin/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/sample/admin/css/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

thank you.

Comment: Can you post the references to the JS/CSS?

Comment: Post your CSS/HTML, I would guess you've done something to conflict with the jqueryUI css/html. -> Other question, did you include the jqueryUI CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported jQuery-UI CSS into your project? You can utilize what they provide, or [roll your own](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). The jQuery UI dialog relies on this to make everything look "pretty."

Comment: @Putersmit - Are you sure your CSS styles are applying? Based on that screen grab you posted, it looks as though it's the default "no-style."

Comment: the styles and js are showing in net in firebug and if i use web developer over the title area it is coming from css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css